# How to display 2 values on leaflet control search result(tooltip)

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet, react-leaflet

i'm using leaflet-control-search to search for markers. https://opengeo.tech/maps/leaflet-search/examples/outside.html
markers are stored in json like this

```
[{"loc":["lat","lng"],"title":"black","region":"West-Kilimajaro"}]
```

in the script above its only displaying 1 value:[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLrUg.png)

i want to display 2(two) values 'title and 'colour';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

i finally found the solution second attribute is suppose to be added as follows

```
 for(i in data) {
 var title = data[i].title,region=data[i].region,
 loc = data[i].loc, 
 marker = new L.Marker(new L.latLng(loc), {title: title,region:region} );
 marker.bindPopup('title: '+ title );
 markersLayer.addLayer(marker);}
```

---

markers are stored in json should look like this

```
{"loc":[-3.3869, 36.6830], "title": "aquamarinee", "region": "West-Kilimanaro"}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the example on project's github  repo at
[Project's Github example html](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search/blob/master/examples/simple.html)

```
////////////populate map with markers from sample data
for(i in data) {
    var title = data[i].title,  //value searched
        loc = data[i].loc,      //position found
        marker = new L.Marker(new L.latLng(loc), {title: title} );//se property searched
    marker.bindPopup('title: '+ title );
    markersLayer.addLayer(marker);
}
```

To add extra values to the marker , you update this line with the extra fields

```
marker.bindPopup('title: '+ title + ' color:' data[i].color);
```

Comment: thanks for that but what i needed is to search 2 attributes [value1, value2]. The tooltip to give result like this. 'black color'

Comment: do you want to search on 2 attributes or display the tooltip ? If for search then do it here marker = new L.Marker(new L.latLng(loc), {title: title, 'color': data[i].color} );/

Comment: I want them to display on tooltip